# Generating "fake persons" with Mathematica?

Tags: machine-learning

Similar to [this site](https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/), does Wolfram have some capacity to generate "fake humans" (for a cool demonstration)?

Comment: It looks like the code is written in python, so the answer is yes.  As for an actual command? `RandomImage[1, {100, 100}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]` will do it eventually, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica has full capacity to build complex neural network, GANs included. However, if the NN isn't in the [Wolfram's repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/) of pre-trained models, you will need to build and train it yourself. And for this you need data, time and knowledge how to do it.

In other words, Mathematica can generate human faces in theory, but to make it possible one is likely to do a lot of work.

P.S. If you want to show any generative abilities, look for the pre-trained [Sketch-RNN](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Sketch-RNN-Trained-on-QuickDraw-Data) or [Photo to Van Gogh](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/CycleGAN-Photo-to-Van-Gogh-Translation)